# Encoding problems while extracting NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, utf-8, nsdictionary

I have a `JSON` file with texts and titles. Titles are in English language, but texts sometimes include cyrillic symbols. When I extract `JSON` to `NSDictionary` everything seems to be good, because log shows me english and `UTF`  symbols:

> \U00c8\U00f1\U00f2\U00ee\U00f0\U00e8\U00df about...

But when I try to get a string from `NSDictionary` with this value it gives me strange symbols:

**Èñòîðèß about...**

It seems like there is everything allright before I try to extract any specific value from the dictionary. So I need help to understand how to get the same exact (English and UTF symbols) value which shows me when I `NSLog` the whole dictionary.

This is how I get the value now: `NSLog(@"text: %@", dict[@"results"][0][@"text"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you haven't encoded your data properly. See your json file in UTF-8: 
[image]

That's why you can not decode it into normal NSString